# AS3: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Here is my entire debugged error:

```
Car initiated: [object MovieClip]
Wheel initiated: [object MovieClip]
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at com.George.MegaAmazingApp.Components::Wheel/clickHandler()[C:\Documents and Settings\reithg\My Documents\Classes\com\George\MegaAmazingApp\Components\Wheel.as:24]
[UnloadSWF] GeorgesMegaAmazingApp.swf
Test Movie terminated.
```

**Car.as:**

```
package com.George.MegaAmazingApp.Components
{

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Car extends MovieClip
    {
        public var carObj:MovieClip;

        public function Car(carObj:MovieClip)
        {
            trace("Car initiated: " + carObj)
            this.carObj = carObj;
        }

        public function Accelerate(speed:Number)
        {
             carObj.y -= speed;
        }

    }

}
```

**Wheel.as**

```
package com.George.MegaAmazingApp.Components
{
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Wheel extends Car
    {
        public var rotated:Number;
        public var wheelObj:MovieClip;

        public function Wheel(wheelObj:MovieClip, carObj:MovieClip)
        {
            super(carObj);
            this.carObj = carObj;
            this.wheelObj = wheelObj;
            trace("Wheel initiated: " + wheelObj);
            wheelObj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
        }
        private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, super.Accelerate(2));
        }

    }

}
```

and my SWF that initiates it:

```
import com.George.MegaAmazingApp.Components.*;

var wheelObj:Wheel = new Wheel(this.wheel,this.car);
```

Anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Wheel extends Car? I see strange things driving by in my head know. Anyway, it is carObj that is 'null' but nowhere in the code you provided can I see how it is instantiated...

Comment: The wheel is actually the steering wheel and works as a remote control for the car. carObj should be `this.car` (i'm new to OOP so it is likely I have missed something I don't know about, new as in a couple of hours new).

Comment: Yes, but where is `this.car` instantiated? Because it is obviously `null`.

Comment: @RIAstar it is drawn onto the stage, and traces [object MovieClip]. (The function Accelerate works and plays once before the error hits). Not entirely sure what you mean by instantiated but I think `public var carObj:MovieClip;` in Car.as

Comment: Sorry, didn't look carefully enough: its actually 'stage' that is null and not 'carObj' (as explained by kapep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit*: The `stage` property is set to `null`, until the object (or one of its parents) is added to the stage. So either use the stage of `wheelObj` or add the Wheel  to the stage first. If you don't want to display the Wheel instance itself, there's no need to extend `MovieClip`.

```
private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    //  event.currentTarget is the wheelObject here
    event.currentTarget.stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Accelerate);
}
```

Anyway you don't need to add listeners to the stage, adding them to the steering wheel itself would work to:

```
private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Accelerate);
}
```

Note that you must provide a function as argument, not a function call. So you need to change the `accelerate` function too.

```
private var speed:int = 2; 

public function accelerate(e:Event)  // best practice:use camelCase function names
{
    carObj.y -= speed;
}
```

Comment: @George You need to import the event class in `Car` as well. `import flash.events.Event;`

Answer (score 0):

Test if the stage exist (trace(stage)), (MovieClip().stage should be valid if your MovieClip is on the displaylist and stage is present). Also your call to super.Accelerate(2) is wrong. If you extend car you could just call Accelerate(2).

You could listen to ENTER_FRAME without accessing the stage if your MovieClip is again.. on the displaylist. this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,handleEnterFrame).

Answer (score 0):

Also, I would not add an ENTER_FRAME eventlistener in response to a click.

But if you do, make sure you don't add multiple listeners:

```
private function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(!hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME))
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Accelerate);
    }
}
```

And as a sidenote, the Accelerate function is not accelrating anything right now. It is moving the Car at a constant pace. The action is more like Run() or something like that. But that has nothing to do with your actual question so... *sidenote*

Comment: I realise, and will expand upon it :P.